# A button which navigates to different view controllers depending on the condition

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, segue, xcode-storyboard

I am new to IOS. I am making a login view controller in IOS with one button which is sign in. I have two possible `view-controllers` that might be shown when the user click on the sign-in button. I am using `Storyboard` but I can only assign one segue to one button. I don't know how to perform the condition since I seem not to have 100% control over the segue.
Here is my code:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString *stringreponse=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:_responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   // NSLog(@"Split response %@", [splitresponse objectAtIndex:0]);
    if([stringreponse isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wrong username or password" message:@"Wrong username or password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        NSArray *splitresponse=[stringreponse componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
        if([[splitresponse objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"Parent"])
        {
            if([[splitresponse objectAtIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"yes"])
            {
                //seguechoice=@"showParentRegistration";
               //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showParentRegistration" sender:self ];
            }else{
                //seguechoice=@"showSohoDashboard";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please print `stringreponse` result.

Comment: assign segue through viewController to other two viewControllers and give two different identifiers to each of these two controllers and then perform the operation which ever you want.

Comment: Thanx just figured it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can assign one segue to one UI control but you can assign many to a viewContoller. Simply add all of them to the viewController, give each a different id and then call those id's

```
if([[splitresponse objectAtIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"yes"])
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showParentRegistration" sender:self ];
}
else
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showSohoDashboard" sender:self ];
}
```

Comment: Thanx Simon, also just figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 connection in storyboard from your source view controller to destination view controller (not button). Insert two different identifiers and when the button is pressed do condition and run a segue depends on the condition:

```
if(CONDITION TO RUN SEGUE !)
{
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SEGUEIDENTIFIER1" sender:self ];
}else {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SEGUEIDENTIFIER2" sender:self ];
}
```